# Difference between UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate and didReceiveRemoteNotification

Tags: ios, swift, ios10

How iOS behaves when we implement both didReceiveRemoteNotification as well as UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate method -

```
  optional public func userNotificationCenter(_ center: 
  UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, 
  withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Swift.Void)
```

As per documentation didReceiveRemoteNotification is deprecated but if app has implemented both delegate method, which one get call for iOS 10 app as well as iOS 9 app on XCode 8 (swift 3)?

Comment: where in documentation does it say `didReceiveRemoteNotification` is deprecated?

Comment: - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo NS_DEPRECATED_IOS(3_0, 10_0, "Use UserNotifications Framework's -[UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate willPresentNotification:withCompletionHandler:] or -[UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate didReceiveNotificationResponse:withCompletionHandler:] for user visible notifications and -[UIApplicationDelegate application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:] for silent remote notifications");

Comment: Oh OK I see. To be honest I don't *think* your question has much of a value. Just don't do it. The result is unexpected. A more general question is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42586403/what-happens-when-you-run-deprecated-code-in-swift), I guess that's what you meant to ask

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What happens when you run deprecated code in swift?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42586403/what-happens-when-you-run-deprecated-code-in-swift)

Answer (score 26):

Basically you are asking two questions,

1. Title: Difference between UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate and didReceiveRemoteNotification?
2. Body: How iOS behaves when we implement both didReceiveRemoteNotification as well as UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate method

Answering #1 (according to Apple docs):

- Deprecated:
  `application(:didReceiveRemoteNotification:)`
- For **remote-silent** notifications:
  `application(:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:)`
- For **remote-not-silent** notifications:

  - When app is on background: `userNotificationCenter(:didReceive:withCompletionHandler:)`
  - When app is on foreground: `userNotificationCenter(:willPresent:withCompletionHandler:)`
- When app **will be launched** from notification (look for the notification on `launchOptions?[.remoteNotification]`): `application(:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)`

Answering #2:

If you implement `UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate` methods, `application(:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:)` will not be called for remote-not-silent notifications.

`application(:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:)` will be called only for remote-silent notifications.

If you are wondering why, you can take a look a this [article](http://cleanswifter.com/ios-10-local-notifications/)