# SLComposeViewController.isAvailable always return false

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to create a share on facebook button using this code

```
func shareOnFacebook(){
        if SLComposeViewController.isAvailable(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeFacebook) {
            let fbShare:SLComposeViewController = SLComposeViewController(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeFacebook)
            delegate?.loadNewScreen(controller: fbShare)
        }
}
```

but it looks like facebook service is always off. I already have facebook  app installed and I am logged in. anyone know what's the problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those functions have been disabled in iOS 11. Apple removed the social access through the settings app. Though no, this won't work, sorry. You have to implement your own sharing components. Twitter wrote an artile about migrating to iOS 11: https://dev.twitter.com/twitterkit/ios/migrate-social-framework

**Edit:**

Just found out that not the calls are deprecated but the social constants: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/social/social_constants

Comment: Wow! I think including facebook SDK and twitter SDK just to add share button is horrible!

Comment: Hey @dotfreelancer, I know that's not the answer you did expect but would you mind accepting this answer? It might help people experiencing a similar issue and will help getting your question noticed. For more information, take a look at our [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).

Comment: sure @cldrr. thanks for help

Comment: Sorry if this is a stupid question but for me, SLComposeViewController works perfectly fine in my code with iOS 12, although Xcode notifies me it is deprecated. Even though it is bad practice to use deprecated code, could I still publish my app with SLComposeViewController? Or would Apple reject it?

Comment: @don https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42586403/what-happens-when-you-run-deprecated-code-in-swift

Comment: Thank you cldrr, very insightful

Comment: Unfortunately, since the time of this answer, Twitter have also discontinued support for Twitter Kit, which further narrows the available options: https://blog.twitter.com/developer/en_us/topics/tools/2018/discontinuing-support-for-twitter-kit-sdk.html

Comment: It looks like Twitter's API endpoints are the expected alternative now: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/post-and-engage/overview

Comment: Do you have any insight as to what this means in practice? The constants are deprecated but for Twitter at least, this still works (as long as you ignore the isAvailable check). It is the best UX and given that TwitterKit is deprecated the only alternative (REST API) is sub optimal. Thoughts?