# What's gonna happen if using Deprecated Button Properties in future iOS?

Tags: ios, swift

I was trying to use [imageEdgeInests](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibutton/1624034-imageedgeinsets) to make the edge inset bigger, but the document says it's available in ios 2.0 - 15.0. (deprecated)
Since my app needs to support ios14, I used imageEdgeInsets for now, but what's gonna happen if an iPhone with future ios (like ios 16?) runs the code? (and if I don't add #available and UIButton.Configuration code) Is it gonna crash the app?

Comment: Duplicated with: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68328038/imageedgeinsets-was-deprecated-in-ios-15-0

Comment: I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42586403/what-happens-when-you-run-deprecated-code-in-swift) on Stackoverflow.